# What is the difference between cin and cout in C++?

Tags: c++, input, output, iostream

I don't understand how these two differ. Feels unnecessarily complicated and kind of redundant. My teacher keeps saying it's two different functions but when i do c in it wont print anything -- I'm not sure if this is a software issue or whether my teacher is giving me poor information.

For example: cin << var1 and then it won't graph my data...can't seem to fix this and my teacher says I'm a lost cause, I don't understand. How can I graph these features without some input information? I don't think my professor fully understands. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: one is for input and one is for output. What is the specific difficulty that you are having? Do you have a code example?

Answer (score 4):

C++ programs operate under the assumption that the program has one input source (accessible via `cin`) and two output streams, one for regular output (accessible via `cout`) and one for reporting errors (accessible via `cerr`).

(There's also `clog`, which is like `cout` but which doesn't buffer its output. I've almost never seen it used in practice).

Because `cin` is just for input, you can use it to read values but not for writing values. Similarly, you can write to `cout` and `cerr`, but you can't read from them.

I'm guessing (?) that C++ didn't combine all of these into a single source (a hypothetical "`call`") because of the asymmetry of having two different output streams and one input stream. Though in principle it would have been possible to do this.